# How to grab a text from a particular tag?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have the following source and I want to get text from a particular attribute of tag `image`
[image]

I'm able to get to the image tag using the following xpath.

`//*[name()='g' and contains(@entityid, '61042482270050282')]/*[name()='image']`

But I do not know how I can grab the text that is underlined in red in the image that is `down_state_16x16` using python in selenium

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

The text you want is the filename from a URL in the `xlink:href` attribute of the element. To get the value from an attribute, you need to use `element.get_attribute()`. From there, you would need to parse the URL down to the filename + extension and then split on '.' to just get the filename.

The code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

href = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "img").get_attribute("xlink:href")
a = urlparse(href)
print(os.path.basename(a.path).split('.')[0])
```